# Create custom x axis labels for stacked line graph

Tags: jqplot

This is what my line chart looks like currently:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the numbers at the bottom and replace them with something custom... and less intervals. How would I do this? I've looked at jqplot examples and documentation and Haven't been able to find what I'm looking for. My code for this currently:

Data:

```
"intervalProgressChart": {
    "new": [11,6,13,7,6,6,6,14,13,8,15,14,10,14,8,13,6,8,15,14,8,8,12,13,12,10,9,7,14,8,14,12,12,13,8,7,6,10,7,9,8,14,10,13,12,13,14,9,13,10,9,10,11,13,10,12,11,12,11,13,7,6,6,14,12,7,14,12,6,8,9,7,8,15,7,10,14,6,7,7,15,15,9,15,6,10,11,6,8,9,10,8,14,14,5,10,10],
    "pending_packaging": [4,3,4,3,1,3,4,5,3,2,5,1,3,5,4,4,2,4,5,2,4,2,3,4,2,2,4,1,3,4,2,5,1,4,2,3,1,2,4,4,2,5,5,3,5,2,5,1,4,4,1,4,4,2,2,3,4,4,5,1,2,3,3,3,2,4,1,1,4,4,2,3,2,5,3,3,2,3,2,2,1,4,5,3,3,4,2,1,2,2,3,1,5,4,5,5,5],
    "pending_delivery": [8,7,6,7,8,5,8,7,5,7,6,7,8,8,9,4,9,6,7,6,7,4,3,4,6,6,5,8,5,7,7,4,4,3,7,4,5,6,5,6,6,7,5,4,4,4,7,5,4,8,7,9,5,8,4,7,5,4,8,3,7,3,3,4,8,6,5,6,8,5,5,6,9,7,3,8,6,6,6,5,5,5,4,4,8,5,7,6,9,6,7,5,4,5,3,4,7]
}
```

Code:

```
$("#intervalProgressChart")
.width(Math.max(600, $(window).width()-100))
.css("clear","both");
$.jqplot("intervalProgressChart", [ data["new"], 
                                    data.pending_packaging, 
                                    data.pending_delivery ] {
    title: "Artifacts in Process for the last 48 hours, last updated " + lastUpdated,
    series: [
             {label: "New"},
             {label: "Pending Packaging"},
             {label: "Pending Delivery"}/*,
             {label: "Delivered"},
             {label: "Error"},
             {label: "Aborted"},
             {label: "Express"}*/
    ],
    seriesColors: [ "#77a22d", "#0099c4", "#621f95" ],
    stackSeries : true,
    showMarker : false,
    highlighter : {
        show : true,
        showTooltip : false
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            pad: 0
        }
    },
    seriesDefaults : {
        fill : true,
    },
    legend : {
        show : true,
        placement : 'outsideGrid'
    },
    grid : {
        drawBorder : false,
        shadow : false
    }
});
```

I tried putting labels onto one of the data sets based on something I saw [**here**](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/axisLabelsRotatedText.html)... like this:

Data:

```
"intervalProgressChart": {
    "new": [["48 hours ago", 11],["", 6],["", 13],["", 7],["", 6],["", 6],["", 6],["", 14],["", 13],["", 8],["", 15],["", 14],["", 10],["", 14],["", 8],["", 13],["", 6],["", 8],["", 15],["", 14],["", 8],["", 8],["", 12],["", 13],["", 12],["", 10],["", 9],["", 7],["", 14],["", 8],["", 14],["", 12],["", 12],["", 13],["", 8],["", 7],["", 6],["", 10],["", 7],["about 24 hours ago",9],["", 8],["", 14],["", 10],["", 13],["", 12],["", 13],["", 14],["", 9],["", 13],["", 10],["", 9],["", 10],["", 11],["", 13],["", 10],["", 12],["", 11],["", 12],["", 11],["", 13],["", 7],["", 6],["", 6],["", 14],["", 12],["", 7],["", 14],["", 12],["", 6],["", 8],["", 9],["", 7],["", 8],["", 15],["", 7],["", 10],["", 14],["", 6],["", 7],["", 7],["", 15],["", 15],["", 9],["", 15],["", 6],["", 10],["", 11],["", 6],["", 8],["", 9],["", 10],["", 8],["", 14],["", 14],["", 5],["", 10],["Current time", 10]],
    "pending_packaging": [4,3,4,3,1,3,4,5,3,2,5,1,3,5,4,4,2,4,5,2,4,2,3,4,2,2,4,1,3,4,2,5,1,4,2,3,1,2,4,4,2,5,5,3,5,2,5,1,4,4,1,4,4,2,2,3,4,4,5,1,2,3,3,3,2,4,1,1,4,4,2,3,2,5,3,3,2,3,2,2,1,4,5,3,3,4,2,1,2,2,3,1,5,4,5,5,5],
    "pending_delivery": [8,7,6,7,8,5,8,7,5,7,6,7,8,8,9,4,9,6,7,6,7,4,3,4,6,6,5,8,5,7,7,4,4,3,7,4,5,6,5,6,6,7,5,4,4,4,7,5,4,8,7,9,5,8,4,7,5,4,8,3,7,3,3,4,8,6,5,6,8,5,5,6,9,7,3,8,6,6,6,5,5,5,4,4,8,5,7,6,9,6,7,5,4,5,3,4,7]
}
```

Code:

```
...
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        angle: 30
                    },
                    pad: 0
                }
            },
...
```

But then I end up with something really goofy...

[image]

...and I'd rather just provide data in the options if possible, like...

```
xaxis: {
    labels: ["48 hours ago", "24 hours ago", "Current time"],
    labelInterval: 48 //at half hour intervals this would be every 24 hours
    ...
```

---

**Additional tries based on feedback:**

---

Tried using this labeled data:

```
    "new": [["48 hours ago", 11],["", 6],["", 13],["", 7],["", 6],["", 6],["", 6],["", 14],["", 13],["", 8],["", 15],["", 14],["", 10],["", 14],["", 8],["", 13],["", 6],["", 8],["", 15],["", 14],["", 8],["", 8],["", 12],["", 13],["", 12],["", 10],["", 9],["", 7],["", 14],["", 8],["", 14],["", 12],["", 12],["", 13],["", 8],["", 7],["", 6],["", 10],["", 7],["",9],["", 8],["", 14],["", 10],["", 13],["", 12],["", 13],["", 14],["", 9],["", 13],["", 10],["", 9],["", 10],["", 11],["", 13],["", 10],["", 12],["", 11],["", 12],["", 11],["", 13],["", 7],["", 6],["", 6],["", 14],["", 12],["", 7],["", 14],["", 12],["", 6],["", 8],["", 9],["", 7],["", 8],["", 15],["", 7],["", 10],["", 14],["", 6],["", 7],["", 7],["", 15],["", 15],["", 9],["", 15],["", 6],["", 10],["", 11],["", 6],["", 8],["", 9],["", 10],["", 8],["", 14],["", 14],["", 5],["", 10],["Current time", 10]],
    "pending_packaging": [["48 hours ago", 4],["", 3],["", 4],["", 3],["", 1],["", 3],["", 4],["", 5],["", 3],["", 2],["", 5],["", 1],["", 3],["", 5],["", 4],["", 4],["", 2],["", 4],["", 5],["", 2],["", 4],["", 2],["", 3],["", 4],["", 2],["", 2],["", 4],["", 1],["", 3],["", 4],["", 2],["", 5],["", 1],["", 4],["", 2],["", 3],["", 1],["", 2],["", 4],["", 4],["", 2],["", 5],["", 5],["", 3],["", 5],["", 2],["", 5],["", 1],["", 4],["", 4],["", 1],["", 4],["", 4],["", 2],["", 2],["", 3],["", 4],["", 4],["", 5],["", 1],["", 2],["", 3],["", 3],["", 3],["", 2],["", 4],["", 1],["", 1],["", 4],["", 4],["", 2],["", 3],["", 2],["", 5],["", 3],["", 3],["", 2],["", 3],["", 2],["", 2],["", 1],["", 4],["", 5],["", 3],["", 3],["", 4],["", 2],["", 1],["", 2],["", 2],["", 3],["", 1],["", 5],["", 4],["", 5],["", 5],["Current time",5]],
    "pending_delivery": [["48 hours ago", 8],["", 7],["", 6],["", 7],["", 8],["", 5],["", 8],["", 7],["", 5],["", 7],["", 6],["", 7],["", 8],["", 8],["", 9],["", 4],["", 9],["", 6],["", 7],["", 6],["", 7],["", 4],["", 3],["", 4],["", 6],["", 6],["", 5],["", 8],["", 5],["", 7],["", 7],["", 4],["", 4],["", 3],["", 7],["", 4],["", 5],["", 6],["", 5],["", 6],["", 6],["", 7],["", 5],["", 4],["", 4],["", 4],["", 7],["", 5],["", 4],["", 8],["", 7],["", 9],["", 5],["", 8],["", 4],["", 7],["", 5],["", 4],["", 8],["", 3],["", 7],["", 3],["", 3],["", 4],["", 8],["", 6],["", 5],["", 6],["", 8],["", 5],["", 5],["", 6],["", 9],["", 7],["", 3],["", 8],["", 6],["", 6],["", 6],["", 5],["", 5],["", 5],["", 4],["", 4],["", 8],["", 5],["", 7],["", 6],["", 9],["", 6],["", 7],["", 5],["", 4],["", 5],["", 3],["", 4],["Current time",7]]
```

Got this graph:

[image]

Comment: jqplot doesn't actually do any data crunching for you. If you want it crunched (e.g. combine adjacent intervals into one data point) you're going to have to pre-process the data.

Comment: @amphetamachine I was trying to have basically pre-processed data in my second attempt on this post. ..."new": [["48 hours ago", 11],... but it didn't work out well for me. I'm not really sure if that's what you meant, but I'm open to whatever I need to do to get this to show up how I want.

Comment: Also, I don't want multiple data points combined into one, I just don't need labels for very many of those points... and then change the labels (the 123456.. doesn't mean anything in this chart). By default in the first graph it seems to be labeling only ever 5 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting the `axes.xaxis.ticks` property of the `options` parameter to this:

```
["48 Hours Ago"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","24 Hours Ago"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","Current"]
```

Basically, every column that I wanted to leave blank I had to put a space in. I assume that jqplot checks for a truthy value and if so replaces the default value with it... because if you put an empty string it will revert to the default iterative values.

This is kind of annoying to do, but in this case it doesn't need to be flexible as far as numbers. If I had to be flexible I suppose I use the length of one of the series to generate the ticks accordingly.

---

Thanks to ampetamachine for pointing out the `ticks` property (+1). However, that answer didn't work as it was on `axesDefaults` which would put these on both the X and Y axes which would definitely not be desirable and I am not sure what the `x_val`s would be replaced with. This answer will work for someone with the same situation. I am still curious if there is a better way to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use custom labels for your x axis, you can organize your data points by series like so:

```
$(thing).jqplot([
    // series 1
    [
        ["Label 1", 12],
        ["Label 2", 34]
    ],
    // series 2
    [
        ["Label 1", 56],
        ["Label 2", 78]
    ]
]);
```

If you want to keep your data like you have it (i.e. `{"Series Name":[val,val,val]}`) you can use the following syntax to use x axis ticks that *aren't* auto-calculated:

```
$(thing).jqplot(myData,
    // options
    {
        axesDefaults: {
            ticks: [
                [ x_val1, "Label 1" ],
                [ x_val2, "Label 2" ],
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
);
```

[Here's a link](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html) to the documentation on the options.

Comment: I've updated my question to show what happened when I tried labeling the data on all 3 series... I'll try the second option you provided now.

Comment: Okay, `axesDefaults` will apply to both axes. I put the following in `axes.xaxis` and I'm seeing what I want now (the spaces are actually necessary to override defaults): `ticks: ["48 Hours Ago"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","24 Hours Ago"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","Current"]`

Comment: What I have in the above comment is working... feels like there should be a better way though :S

Comment: I know, but what you did is a neat hack. I wouldn't have guessed this would work.